# use a structure declared in C shared library

Tags: c, structure, shared-libraries

I have declared a structure in a shared library and I want to use it on my application but I don't know how to use it.
It's not possible to re-declare it in my application due to compiler incompatibility.
what is the solution?

Comment: share your code in question

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "compiler incompatibility"?

Comment: @RSahu Two different compiler may compile a single `struct` in different way

Comment: @Shahryar, In that case, you won't be able use the shared library in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `struct` doesn't exist *anywhere* in a C program or shared library etc. After compilation, a `struct` only exists as a bunch of offsets into a "blob" where instructions will read from / write to.

If you want to link against a library that uses some `struct` as part of its API, you *must* include a header file that declares the structure *exactly* as was used to compile the library.

Comment: So what if two compilers are different?

Comment: Different compilers could yield pretty nasty results too. Namely with regard to datatype sizes (is `long` 32 or 64 bits?), packing/alignment issues, etc.  You have to be really careful when you're not using the same compiler as was used to build the .so

Comment: @Shahryar then you need to make sure they compile your `struct` the same way.